# Laravel dependency injection into custom non-controller class fails in PHPUnit

Tags: laravel, dependency-injection, phpunit

all.

For a Laravel project I'm working on, I've started to use Dependency Injection in order to mock classes in my tests.  However, I've found that if I try to inject into a custom class with no explicit parent, two things are true:

1. The dependency injection works correctly when running the application
2. The injection fails when running tests in PHPUnit

Here is some sample code similar to what I'm using:

**DemoController**

```
//  The controller we're testing
class DemoController extends Controller
{
    //  The injection and constructor
    private $helpLayer1;

    public function __construct(HelpLayer1 $helpLayer1)
    {
        $this->helpLayer1 = $helpLayer1;
    }

    ...

    //  The test function I call
    public function testDeps()
    {
        $this->helpLayer1->testLayer1();
    }
}
```

**HelperLayer1**

```
//  Our first helper class
class HelperLayer1
{
    private $helpLayer2;

    public function __construct(HelpLayer2 $helpLayer2)
    {
        $this->helpLayer2 = $helpLayer2;
    }

    ...

    //  The testing function
    public function testLayer1()
    {
        //  When called via route, this dumps the actual object
        //  When called via test, this returns null
        dd($this->helperLayer2);
    }
}
```

**Helper1ServiceProvider**

```
class Helper1ServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('HelperLayer1', function()
        {
            return new HelperLayer1(App::make('HelperLayer2'));
        });
    }

    [OR]

    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('HelperLayer1', 'HelperLayer1');
    }
}
```

**Helper2ServiceProvider**

```
class Helper2ServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('HelperLayer2', 'HelperLayer2');
    }
}
```

I'm relatively new to using DI, so I'm not entirely sure that this set-up is correct, but I'm at a loss.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thank you!

Comment: `HelperLayer1`'s constructor is trying to inject `HelpLayer2`, but you are binding `HelperLayer2`.  Is this a typo in your code or just the question?

Comment: This is mock code.  However, it does reflect the setup I'm currently using, and unless I'm not paying attention, there are no typos compared to what I'm using in the project.  Is the binding itself the issue?